# How do I link the libSCFoundationCMSApp.a & libPMAnalytics-r69.a libs and fix this error

Tags: iphone

I am taking over a really old iPhone project.  I am getting these errors when I compile. Do  I have libSCFoundationCMSApp.a & libPMAnalytics-r69.a in the wrong locations or am I just missing the libs that the app needs to properly use them?

```
".objc_class_name_NSNull", referenced from:

  literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNull in libSCFoundationCMSApp.a(NSDictionaryAdditions.o)
  literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNull in libSCFoundationCMSApp.a(XMLAdditions.o)
  literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNull in libSCFoundationCMSApp.a(FMDatabase.o)
  literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNull in libPMAnalytics-r69.a(Beacon.o)
  literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNull in libPMAnalytics-r69.a(PMJSONUtils.o)
  literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNull in libPMAnalytics-r69.a(PMFBXMLHandler.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me more likely that those libraries aren't linked properly to Foundation.framework.

Its complaining that it can't find the `NSNull` class name as a symbol and that it was referenced from within those libraries.

Comment: How do I link them to the foundation framework or test to see if they are properly linked?

Comment: You'll need the project they were built from. You'll likely have to recompile them, ensuring that Foundation is linked in the process.

Comment: Though, I could be wrong, its difficult to tell without seeing the entire picture. Maybe your main app isn't linking Foundation?

Comment: I think its linking foundation because i removed and re-added that framework and that set of errors is now gone.  The only errors I am left with are all related to the custom UI libs that the app uses.  I inherited this app.  Its based on the 2.0 and really old.  They cant get the old dev to provide the source files of those two libs so all I have is the compiled source .a files for them.